# Ubuntu Install Flashing Dot

Tags: system-installation, graphics, 16.04

So I decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a custom build I just made. It's one of those "budget" builds but like realllllly budgety (scrap parts I had around my house). So the first time I try to install Ubuntu, my monitor says input out of range and won't display. I figured that my old 32 Xeon didn't have onboard graphics so I dug up some random old graphics card. So far no display error but there is this flashing dot in the top left that has been flashing for like 10 min. Is it normal with a slow pc? Or did I screw something up.

Update, I restarted it and it did the Ubuntu loading dots thing, then the white flashing dot for like 5 secs then now it's doing the ubuntu dot loading again. What is going on?!?!?

Update, back to the flashing white dot again :(

Comment: Try installing the server edition of Ubuntu 16.04 just to see if it works, because the server edition does not have a GUI. So if it works, you know that the issue is related to the display.

Comment: Wait a minute, were you even able to make it through the installation?

Comment: Nope lol. This is all in installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had that recently too. I needed to install the NVIDIA graphics driver to fix that (and a whole lot of other problems).